# Name for a test to find the best match for a given image in a library of images (OpenCV?)

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have looked through all the OpenCV documentation that I could find and googled for what I'm looking for, but I think I must be using the wrong terminology.

What I want to do is something similar to template matching, but I do not need to search for instances of my image in another image. I need to compare my image to a library of other images and determine which is the best match. **Is there a name for this kind of matching?**

If there is no existing library for it, I am planning just to use a correlation function for each image in the library and take the best match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you want to match a template in a lot of images.

You can create a loop for matching teplates to images.
And find minMaxLoc and values.

So you can see which image how match to template.

Comment: Right. That's my plan if there is no other framework for this type of matching. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Reviewing this after a long time, this is actually what I ended up using a lot. The big weakness is that simple template matching is not scale invariant. So you have to have foreknowledge of all the resolutions. For scale invariance, you can pay lots of money for a license and use SIFT/SURF, or you can use the new [BRISK](http://www.asl.ethz.ch/people/lestefan/personal/BRISK) technique.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking for SIFT/SURF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found those algorithms as well, but as I understand them, they are simply very advanced versions of template matching within images. Hopefully I will not need something that complex.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like image matching or image comparison (another keyword you might search for is image registration but that is a bit different).

Comment: "Image Matching". That sounds like the right phrase. It looks like this is most developed in the intellectual property arena. I feel silly now with such a simple answer, but I believe I was missing it because I always included OpenCV in my searches. Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 1):

One simple technique could be to compare the histograms of the two images. Check out this link for more information

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/histograms.html?highlight=histograms#cv-comparehist

You should also look at the sample programs that come with openCV called find_obj and find_obj_ferns

Comment: Thanks for that. I can add those to the set of available functions for matching. It seems that is the direction this is going anyway.